# Why does CircleCI bother with circleci-php-* while I am removing MySQL from it?

Tags: package-management, mysql, php

Why does this command remove also circleci-php-7.0.11? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on CircleCI.

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

How can I tell CircleCI NOT to remove any versions of `circleci-php-`? I do want it to remove `mysql-server`, `mysql-client` and `mysql-common`.